# Create Powershell arraylist inside a loop

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

Want to create a Powershell 'ArrayList' inside a loop, array name is read from a csv.
This works,

```
$TestServers = "TestServers"
New-Variable -Name "Array_$($TestServers)" -Value @()
(Get-Variable -Name "Array_$($TestServers)")
```

Same way (or a different method) how can I create a PS [System.Collections.ArrayList]?

Thanks ...

Comment: Approach it differently, instead of dynamically defining new variables, use a `hashtable` instead

Comment: `$TestServers = [System.Collections.ArrayList]::new(@('Testserver'))` ?

Comment: If you'd show a little bit more code, we could propably give a better advice. Chances are that you don't even need to manually create an `ArrayList` as PowerShell creates an array automatically when you assign output of a loop to a variable.